# Unable to mux two live streams from webcam using ffmpeg in linux

Tags: ffmpeg, http-live-streaming, multiplexing

We are trying to multiplex two live streams from webcams into an output file using ffmpeg in linux as follows,

```
fmpeg -i "http://10.41.2.57:8090/webcam.asf" -i "http://10.41.2.49:8090/webcam.asf" -map 0:0 -map 1:0 -t 60 "/home/../MuxLiveStream1.flv"
```

ffmpeg stops responding at after a while and the console shows the following output,

```
FFmpeg version SVN-r0.5.9-4:0.5.9-0ubuntu0.10.04.3, Copyright (c) 2000-2009 Fabrice Bellard, et al.
  configuration: --extra-version=4:0.5.9-0ubuntu0.10.04.3 --prefix=/usr --enable-avfilter --enable-avfilter-lavf --enable-vdpau --enable-bzlib --enable-libgsm --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-pthreads --enable-zlib --disable-stripping --disable-vhook --enable-runtime-cpudetect --enable-gpl --enable-postproc --enable-swscale --enable-x11grab --enable-libdc1394 --enable-shared --disable-static
  libavutil     49.15. 0 / 49.15. 0
  libavcodec    52.20. 1 / 52.20. 1
  libavformat   52.31. 0 / 52.31. 0
  libavdevice   52. 1. 0 / 52. 1. 0
  libavfilter    0. 4. 0 /  0. 4. 0
  libswscale     0. 7. 1 /  0. 7. 1
  libpostproc   51. 2. 0 / 51. 2. 0
  built on Jan 24 2013 19:42:59, gcc: 4.4.3

Seems stream 0 codec frame rate differs from container frame rate: 1000.00 (1000/1) -> 2.00 (2/1)
Input #0, flv, from 'http:10.41.2.154:8090/webcam.flv':
  Duration: 00:00:00.00, start: 1587016.579000, bitrate: 200 kb/s
    Stream #0.0: Video: flv, yuv420p, 320x240, 200 kb/s, 2 tbr, 1k tbn, 1k tbc

Seems stream 0 codec frame rate differs from container frame rate: 1000.00 (1000/1) -> 2.00 (2/1)
Input #1, flv, from 'http:10.41.2.57:8090/webcam.flv':
  Duration: 00:00:00.00, start: 1587230.806000, bitrate: 200 kb/s
    Stream #1.0: Video: flv, yuv420p, 320x240, 200 kb/s, 2 tbr, 1k tbn, 1k tbc
Number of stream maps must match number of output streams
```

Is there a mistake in the command or is there anything else that needs to be done?

Comment: The complete ffmpeg console output is missing.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard: I have edited the question. U will find the complete ffmpeg console output now.

Comment: Please format the output for readability instead of simply pasting it. Highlight it with your mouse and click the "Code Sample" button or hit ctrl+k or command+k.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A recent build shows:

```
[flv @ 0x28e4d40] at most one video stream is supported in flv
```

Try a more flexible output container such as Matroska (.mkv) and use a recent build since 0.5.9 is ancient. You can simply [download a Linux build of ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/download.html#LinuxBuilds) or you can follow a [step-by-step guide to compile ffmpeg](http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/UbuntuCompilationGuide).